# Changing data in react-table instantly based on timer in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, timing

I have a bunch of data with timestamps(in milliseconds) and I need to replay that data in the browser based on a timer also running in the browser. I'm using React

What i've got so far is that I'm using an API call to get the data from my sql server and then I store that data in a BTree with the timestamp as a key and the data as a value. The time elapsed is a state and the BTrees are states too. I've tried both BTree and Hashmaps, as I initially thought the long search time in Hashmaps was my issue.

Currently, it doesn't seem to be working and I believe its because my search and retrieval are not fast enough, even with a BTree. The value with time = 0 displays correctly, but all subsequent renders are undefined, i've attached a screen shot to the console debugger below. The numbers are the time in ms, the undefined means I don't have keys of that value, I know that. I'm just not sure how to "sync" them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhhk.png)

I have a large dataset so i'm not sure how to proceed. Is my implementation completely offbase or am I on the right track? Is there a standardized way in doing this?

Here is the relevant code, please let me know if there is anything else I should specify.

```
startTimer() {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time
    })
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState({
      time: Date.now() - this.state.start
    }), 1);
  }

  stopTimer() {
    this.setState({isOn: false})
    clearInterval(this.time)
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({time: 0, isOn: false})
  }

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('/api/world', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
    });
    const body = await response.text();

    this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
  };

  render() {
    let start = (this.state.time == 0) ?
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>start</button> :
      null

    let stop = (this.state.time == 0 || !this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>stop</button>

    let resume = (this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>resume</button>

    let reset = (this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>reset</button>


    //DEBUG HERE
    console.log(this.state.time)
    console.log()

    var data = [{
      name: 'beams',
      aid: beamID,
      bytes: '',
      bytes: this.state.beamTree.get(this.state.time)
    },{
      name: 'cruise',
      aid: cruiseID,
      bytes: '',
      bytes: this.state.cruiseMap.get(this.state.time)
    },{
      name: 'dash',
      aid: dashID,
      bytes: '',
      bytes: this.state.dashMap.get(this.state.time)
    },{
      name: 'radio',
      aid: radioID,
      bytes: '',
      bytes: this.state.radioMap.get(this.state.time)
    },{
      name: 'tc',
      aid: tcID,
      bytes: '',
      bytes: this.state.tcMap.get(this.state.time)
    }]

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="Sidebar">
            <ReactTable
              style={{"minheight" : "100%"}}
              showPagination={false}
              data={data}    
            columns={columns}     
              pageSizeOptions= {[3,9]}
            />
        </div>      
        <div>
        <h3>timer: {this.state.time}</h3>
        {start}
        {resume}
        {stop}
        {reset}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, in case anyone from the future is reading this, I wound up using setInterval. Needs work but here is my App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      response: '',
      get: '',
      post: '',
      responseToPost: '',
      responseToGet: '',
      data: {},
      message: '',
      beamMap: new HashMap(),
      cruiseMap: new HashMap(),
      dashMap: new HashMap(),
      radioMap: new HashMap(),
      tcMap: new HashMap(),
      time: 0,
      isOn: false,
      start: 0,
      end: 0,
      beamBytes: '',
      radioBytes: '',
      cruiseBytes: '',
      dashBytes: '',
      tcBytes: '',
      radioTick: 0,
      cruiseTick: 0,
      dashTick: 0,
      tcTick: 0,
      tick: 0
  }
  this.startCruiseInterval = this.startCruiseInterval.bind(this)
  this.startDashInterval = this.startDashInterval.bind(this)
  this.startTCInterval = this.startTCInterval.bind(this)
  this.startBeamInterval = this.startBeamInterval.bind(this)
  this.startRadioInterval = this.startRadioInterval.bind(this)
  this.startTimeInterval = this.startTimeInterval.bind(this)
  this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this)
  this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this)
  this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this)
}

  //TODO
  //variable vehicle and session
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/session/1/1').then(
      response => response.json()
    ).then(
        json => {
        this.setState({data: json});
        var str = this.state.data

        //Store json data into the appropriate hashmap
        for(var i=0;str.length;i++){
          if(str[i].aid==beamID){
            beamHolder.set(parseInt(str[i].time),str[i].data)
            this.setState({beamMap: beamHolder})
          }else if(str[i].aid==cruiseID){
            cruiseHolder.set(parseInt(str[i].time),str[i].data)
            this.setState({cruiseMap: cruiseHolder})
          }else if(str[i].aid==dashID){
            dashHolder.set(parseInt(str[i].time),str[i].data)
            this.setState({dashMap: dashHolder})
          }else if(str[i].aid==radioID){
            radioHolder.set(parseInt(str[i].time),str[i].data)
            this.setState({radioMap: radioHolder})
          }else if(str[i].aid==tcID){
            tcHolder.set(parseInt(str[i].time),str[i].data)
            this.setState({tcMap: tcHolder})
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }

  startTimeInterval(){
    return this.setState({time: Date.now() - this.state.start})
  }

  startRadioInterval(){
    this.setState({radioBytes: this.state.radioMap.get(this.state.radioTick)})
    this.setState({radioTick: this.state.radioTick + 500})
  }

  startCruiseInterval(){
    this.setState({cruiseBytes: this.state.cruiseMap.get(this.state.cruiseTick)})
    this.setState({cruiseTick: this.state.cruiseTick + 500})
  }

  startDashInterval(){
    this.setState({dashBytes: this.state.dashMap.get(this.state.dashTick)})
    this.setState({dashTick: this.state.dashTick + 500})
  }

  startTCInterval(){
    this.setState({tcBytes: this.state.tcMap.get(this.state.tcTick)})
    this.setState({tcTick: this.state.tcTick + 500})
  }

  startBeamInterval(){
    this.setState({beamBytes: this.state.beamMap.get(this.state.tick)})
    this.setState({tick: this.state.tick + 500})
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time
    })

    this.timer = setInterval(this.startTimeInterval, 1)
    this.beamBytes = setInterval(this.startBeamInterval, 500)
    this.radioBytes = setInterval(this.startRadioInterval, 500)
    this.cruiseBytes = setInterval(this.startCruiseInterval, 500)
    this.dashBytes = setInterval(this.startDashInterval, 500)
    this.tcBytes = setInterval(this.startTCInterval, 500)
  }

  stopTimer() {
    this.setState({isOn: false})
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    clearInterval(this.beamBytes)
    clearInterval(this.radioBytes)
    clearInterval(this.cruiseBytes)
    clearInterval(this.dashBytes)
    clearInterval(this.tcBytes)
  }

  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({time: 0, isOn: false})
    this.setState({beamBytes:''})
    this.setState({radioBytes:''})
    this.setState({cruiseBytes:''})
    this.setState({dashBytes:''})
    this.setState({tcBytes:''})
    this.setState({tick:0})
    this.setState({radioTick:0})
    this.setState({cruiseTick:0})
    this.setState({dashTick:0})
    this.setState({tcTick:0})
  }

  render() {
    let start = (this.state.time == 0) ?
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>start</button> :
      null

    let stop = (this.state.time == 0 || !this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>stop</button>

    let resume = (this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.startTimer}>resume</button>

    let reset = (this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn) ?
      null :
      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>reset</button>

    var data = [{
      name: 'beams',
      aid: beamID,
      bytes: this.state.beamBytes,
    },{
      name: 'cruise',
      aid: cruiseID,  
      bytes: this.state.cruiseBytes
    },{
      name: 'dash',
      aid: dashID,
      bytes: this.state.dashBytes
    },{
      name: 'radio',
      aid: radioID,
      bytes: this.state.radioBytes
    },{
      name: 'tc',
      aid: tcID,
      bytes: this.state.tcBytes
    }]

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="Sidebar">
            <ReactTable
              style={{"minheight" : "100%"}}
              showPagination={false}
              data={data}    
            columns={columns}     
              pageSizeOptions= {[3,9]}
            />
        </div>      
        <div>
        <h3>timer: {this.state.time}</h3>
        {start}
        {resume}
        {stop}
        {reset}
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```